# Delete all files with extension .csv except one- Batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Lets say I have couple of files named:

```
 1. Item-A.csv
 2. Item-B.csv
 3. Total-AB.csv
 4. Pictures.jpeg
```

And I need to delete all with .csv extension except total-av.csv within any directory. So the resulting remaining files are the following in any directory that I am in:

```
 1. Total-AB.csv
 2. Pictures.jpeg
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Will the file always be called Total-AB.csv or could the name change to something else? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: `find -name '*.csv' ! -name 'Total-AB.csv -delete` (run **without** delete first to check the list).

Comment: The file name would always be called total-ab.csv. I have tried for %%i in (*.*) do if not "%%i"=="total-ab.csv" del /q "%%i". But it doesn't take into factor the extension, it removes everything except a file with that name.

Comment: Try `if not "%%~nxi"=="total-ab.csv"` instead. The `n` just gets the filename and the `x` gets the extension.

Comment: I tried above, but still deletes everything including .jpeg extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .bat file:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`dir *.csv /s/b ^| findstr /v /i "Total-AB.csv"`) do (
    echo %%f
    rem del %%f
)
```

Take out the `rem` once it looks like it works as expected.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it does find the files with extension csv. but does not delete anything.

Comment: Yes, the `REM` comments out the line so that it doesn't run. If the echo looks like it works, remove the `REM` command.

Comment: It doesn't handle spaces and some other characters in the path or filename unless you use `del "%%f"` and it will also filter out a file called `"My Total-AB.csv"` etc unless the findstr command is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerShell command to delete every *.csv in all sub folders except for your total-av.csv

```
Dir *.csv -Exclude total-av.csv -R | del
```

Here is the same command without using the batch shortnames.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv -Exclude total-av.csv -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this on a sample folder tree.  Note that it is recursive over an entire folder tree.

```
@echo off
for /r "d:\base\folder" %%a in (*.csv) do if /i not "%%~nxa"=="total-av.csv" del "%%a"
```